# Как сделать отображение только нижней границы?

Tags: android, android-drawable

Есть такая XML разметка в `drawable`, которая рисует чёрную рамку вокруг элемента:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle"  android:layout_height="1dp" android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <stroke
        android:width="1px"
        android:color="#D0D0D0" />

</shape>
```

Можно ли каким-то образом сделать так, чтобы отображалась только нижняя часть этой рамки?

Comment: Попробуйте сделать `layer-list` с линией и гравитацией bottom. Доступа сейчас к студии нет, точно не могу сказать/проверить

Comment: насколько нижняя? типо подчеркивание?

Comment: @pavlofff, да. Именно так.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19238738/android-shape-with-bottom-stroke